# Configuração do XDEBUG no PHP.ini ( CakePHP, AppServ - Apache2.4, NetBeans)

Tags: netbeans, cakephp-2, xdebug

Meus amigos, boa tarde

Sou novo no pedaço, quer dizer, na área de desenvolvimento em PHP e estou fazendo as configurações para debugar uma aplicação em CakePHP 2.6.

Segui toda a documentação do XDEBUG, baixei a versão compatível ao meu PHP 5.6 (Windows 64bits), inclui o arquivo na pasta abaixo, dentro dos meu diretório local, em que uso o AppServ com um servidor apache.

C:\AppServ\php5\ext\php_xdebug-2.5.0-5.6-vc11-x86_64.dll

Após isso, segundo passo, configurei o arquivo PHP.ini

```
zend_extension="C:\AppServ\php5\ext\php_xdebug-2.5.0-5.6-vc11-x86_64.dll"

xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000 (A minha aplicação está rodando na porta 9090. Mas já fiz um teste também atribuindo a porta 9090 e não funcionou).
xdebug.extended_info=1
xdebug.default_enable = On
xdebug.collect_includes = On
xdebug.collect_params = On
xdebug.collect_return = On
xdebug.collect_vars = On
xdebug.dump_globals = On
```

Vocês poderiam me ajudar com alguma dica? O que estou fazendo de errado?

Muito obrigado!

Marcelo

Answer (score -1):

Pra windows é realmente complexo. Se você utilizar o vagrant ou o docker (ou no próprio Linux) você pode usar o Dephpugger.
Dephpugger é uma lib em php pra rodar debugger direto no terminal (tipo o ipdb do Python ou o Byebug do Ruby).

https://github.com/tacnoman/dephpugger

Comment: Obrigado Renato, vou tentar usar o dephpugger e o Unit test do CakePHP